# How do I return the response from an API call with actix-web?

Tags: rust, request, actix-web

I'm trying to get posts from the Rust subreddit and return the response to my frontend.

This is my `App`:

```
App::new()
    .data(Client::default())
    .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
    .service(
        web::resource("/get/rust/posts").route(web::get().to_async(get_rust_posts))
    )
```

handler function:

```
fn get_rust_posts(req: HttpRequest, client: web::Data<Client>) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error> {
  client.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/rust.json") // create request builder
    .header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
    .send() // send http request
    .map_err(Error::from)
    .and_then(|resp| {
      // return resp
    })
}
```

dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "1.0.7"
futures = "0.1.29"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn get_rust_posts(req: HttpRequest, client: web::Data<Client>) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error> {
  client.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/rust.json") // create request builder
    .header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
    .send() // send http request
    .map_err(Error::from)
    .and_then(|resp| Ok::<HttpResponse, Error>(HttpResponse::Ok().streaming(resp)))
}
```

It works on Ubuntu Linux, but [doesn't work on Windows](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1047) at the moment.

Comment: I'll have to keep an eye on that issue. Thanks!